# Understand Arguments in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This may be a stupid question but at Uni we were presented with a Prolog segment that multiplies arrays. It has 4 predicates of which one I cannot understand what it does or how to execute it. Can you give me any hint or explanation?

```
multiply([],_,[]).
multiply([V0|Rest], V1, [Result|Others]):-
    multiply(Rest,V1,Others),
    inner_product(V0,V1,Result).
```

I tried to run the predicate like this:

```
multiply([1,2],3,X).

multiply([[1,2]],[3],X).

multiply([[1,2]],3,X)

multiply([1,2],[3,2],X).
```

but everything returned false.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe inner_product/3 is missing ?

Comment: .. and when the missing predicate is present, use 'trace.' before multiply(..) to see what is is doing under the covers.

Comment: @CapelliC I know it is missing I gave you only a predicate. Not the whole file

Comment: @magus OK I'll bear it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No information has been given about what kind of arguments are expected, but you can determine it by looking at the clauses for `multiply`:

```
multiply([],_,[]).
```

This indicates that the first and third arguments are lists, of some kind.

```
multiply([V0|Rest], V1, [Result|Others]):-
    multiply(Rest,V1,Others),
    inner_product(V0,V1,Result).
```

`inner_product`, though not defined as @CapelliC pointed out, indicates that `V0` and `V1` are *vectors* (or in prolog, lists of *scalar* quantities) of the *same length* by definition of an inner product. And the `Result` value will be a scalar.

So, for `multiply(M1, V, Result).` to succeed:

1. `M1` must be a list of lists, or a matrix. Each inner list *must* be the same length and it must be a list of *scalar* values
2. `V` must be a *list* of *scalar* values, and of the same length as the inner lists of `M1`
3. Inferred by the recursion, `Result` will be a vector (a list) of *scalar* values and the list will have a length equal to the length of `M1` (have the same number of scalars as `M1` has vectors).

In other words, it's following the rules of standard matrix/vector multiplication.

Looking at all the test cases shown, they will all fail because none of them match all 3 criteria above.

```
multiply([1,2],3,X).      % Fails item #1 above
                          % `3` isn't a vector/list
multiply([[1,2]],[3],X).  % Fails item #2 above
                          % length of [3] isn't length of [1,2]
multiply([[1,2]],3,X)     % Fails item #2 above
                          % `3` isn't a vector/list
multiply([1,2],[3,2],X).  % Fails item #1 above
                          % `[1,2]` isn't a list of lists (matrix)
```

So they will all fail just on the basis of not matching the expected configuration of arguments that allow the predicate to succeed.

Try something like:

```
multiply([[1,2,3],[3,2,1]], [1,1,1], X).
```

You should get:

```
X = [6,6]
```

Comment: Thx a lot for you extensive answer! You helped me a lot understand how Prolog works!